# Upload IPA with access account

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipa

My client is not giving credentials of his account, he gives me developer access of his account now I can upload `ipa` in specific user access account. I almost have three account access in one user panel but i'm confused that how I can upload `ipa` in one specific user account base of access through Xcode or another way

Comment: I understand that you have one developer account linked to several teams, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the button to switch between teams you're part of on the top right of AppStore Connect. Inside Xcode just select the right account for code signing (assuming you're using automatic).